# R optim with a hidden restriction

Tags: r, optimization

### Background

I'm doing empirical likelihood maximization, and hit an error. The statistics is a bit complex and I describe the error like following.

### Problem

Suppose I have multivariate function with domain:
[image],
[image]

**And I want to minimize the function in the domain.**

Here is the counter plot for my function, the optimum seems to be x = y = 0.5 and z = 0.

```
if(!require(plotly)){
  install.packages('plotly')
  require(plotly)
}else{
  require(plotly)
}
myfun = function(x,y){
  z <- 1-x-y
  # want to minimiaze f
  f = (x - 0.26)^2 + (y-0.51)^2 + 100*(z+0.6)^2
  return(f) # return f, so that optim can minimize f
}
plot_ly(
  x = seq(0,1,length.out = 101), 
  y = seq(0,1,length.out = 101), 
  z = outer(seq(0,1,length.out = 101), seq(0,1,length.out = 101),FUN = myfun), 
  type = "contour" 
)
```

[image]

### My fail attempt

since z = 1-x-y, I tried with 2 parameters (x,y) and their boundry [0,1].

Code:

```
myobj <- function(para){
  x <- para[1]
  y <- para[2]
  z <- 1-x-y
  # want to minimiaze f
  f = (x - 0.26)^2 + (y-0.51)^2 + 100*(z+1.6)^2
  return(f) # return f, so that optim can minimize f
}
# initialization x=y=0, lower bound (0,0), upper bound (1,1), without restriction on z
optim(par = c(0,0),fn = myobj,method = "L-BFGS-B",lower = c(0,0),upper = c(1,1))
```

Output:

```
$par
[1] 1 1

$value
[1] 36.7877

$counts
function gradient 
       2        2 

$convergence
[1] 0

$message
[1] "CONVERGENCE: NORM OF PROJECTED GRADIENT <= PGTOL"
```

The output shows that x=y=1 is the result, but when x=y=1, z = 1-1-1 = -1 does not in its domain.

I am wondering how can I put my restrition on z and get the right result,using function like `optim`?

Thanks a lot!

### CVXR vs. constrOptim time comparation

```
library(microbenchmark)
library(CVXR)
method_const <- function(){
  myobj <- function(para){
  x <- para[1]
  y <- para[2]
  z <- 1 - x-y
  # want to minimiaze f
  f = (x - 0.26)^2 + (y-0.51)^2 + 100*(z+0.6)^2
  return(f) # return f, so that optim can minimize f
}
  res <- constrOptim(c(0.01,0.01), myobj, NULL,
            ui = rbind(c(1,0),c(-1,0),c(0,1),c(0,-1),c(-1,-1)), 
            ci = c(0,-1,0,-1,-1))
  return(round(c(res$par,res$value),4))
}
method_CVXR <-function(){
  # declaration of variables x, y, and z
  x <- Variable(1)
  y <- Variable(1)
  z <- Variable(1)
  # setup constraints
  cons <- list(sum(gg)==1,gg[1]>=0, gg[2]>=0, gg[3]>=0)
  # formulate objective function
  obj <- Minimize((gg[1] - 0.26)^2 + (gg[2]-0.51)^2 + 100*(gg[3]+0.6)^2)
  problem <- Problem(obj,cons)
  # solve the optimization problem
  res <- solve(problem)
  return(round(c(res$getValue(gg),res$value),4))
}

method_CVXR2 <-function(){
  # declaration of variables x, y, and z
  gg <- Variable(3)
  # setup constraints
  cons <- list(x+y+z==1,x>=0, y>=0, z>=0)
  # formulate objective function
  obj <- Minimize((x - 0.26)^2 + (y-0.51)^2 + 100*(z+0.6)^2)
  problem <- Problem(obj,cons)
  # solve the optimization problem
  res <- solve(problem)
  return(round(c(res$getValue(x),res$getValue(y),res$value),4))
}
time_res = microbenchmark(method_const(),method_CVXR(),method_CVXR2())
print(time_res)
ggplot2::autoplot(time_res)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will be more natural to solve this as a quadratic programming problem. Package *quadprog* provides such a QP solver, except that the problem formulation is a bit clumsy.

```
# objective function as quadratic problem
D <- diag(c(1, 1, 100))
d <- c(0.26, 0.51, -60)

# equality and bound constraints
A <- rbind(c(1,1,1), diag(3))
b <- c(1, 0,0,0)
meq <- 1

s <- solve.QP(D, d, t(A), b, meq)
s$solution
## [1] 0.375 0.625 0.000
```

Time comparisons on my computer are as follows:

```
Unit: milliseconds
                 expr         mean    median
    method_quadprog()        0.035     0.032
       method_solnl()        1.696     1.037
     method_fmincon()        1.677     1.092
 method_constroptim()        2.130     1.644
        method_CVXR()      113.590    97.924
```

REMARK: Please note that `fmincon` is just a wrapper for `solnl`.

The solver behind CVXR is one of the fastest available in R, but building the model is taking some time. That is why CVXR is not efficient for very small problems such as this one, but can be hundreds of times faster than others for quite large problems.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the performance comparison among several approaches

```
> time_res
Unit: milliseconds
                 expr      min        lq       mean    median        uq      max neval
 method_constroptim()   1.8112   1.86370   3.140725   1.97750   2.07470  11.8188    20
     method_fmincon()   1.1804   1.22620   1.633585   1.37365   1.45635   7.0064    20
       method_solnl()   1.0980   1.17495   2.165110   1.27700   1.40575   9.3543    20
        method_CVXR() 111.4424 121.00940 155.573570 129.92280 149.25700 414.5042    20
```

where the code for benchmark is given as below

```
library(microbenchmark)
library(CVXR)
library(pracma)
library(NlcOptim)

# objective function for minimization
f <- function(v) {
  x <- v[1]
  y <- v[2]
  z <- 1- x - y
  r <- (x - 0.26)^2 + (y-0.51)^2 + 100*(z +0.6)^2
}

# constrOptim()
method_constroptim <- function(){
  v0 <- c(0.5,0.5)
  ui <- rbind(c(1,0),c(-1,0),c(0,1),c(0,-1),c(-1,-1))
  ci <- c(0,-1,0,-1,-1)
  constrOptim(c(0.01,0.01), f, NULL, ui = ui,ci = ci)
}

# fmincon() from "pracma" package
method_fmincon <-function(){
  v0 <- c(0.5,0.5,0)
  Aeq <- t(matrix(c(1,1,1)))
  beq <- 1
  lb <- c(0,0,0)
  ub <- c(1,1,1)
  fmincon(v0,f,Aeq = Aeq, beq = beq, lb = lb, ub = ub)
}

# solnl() from "NlcOptim" package
method_solnl <- function() {
  v0 <- c(0.5,0.5,0)
  Aeq <- t(matrix(c(1,1,1)))
  beq <- 1
  lb <- c(0,0,0)
  ub <- c(1,1,1)
  solnl(v0,f,Aeq = Aeq, Beq = beq, lb = lb, ub = ub)
}

# solnl() from "CVXR" package
method_CVXR <-function(){
  x <- Variable(1)
  y <- Variable(1)
  cons <- list(x>=0, y>=0, x+y<=1)
  obj <- Minimize((x - 0.26)^2 + (y-0.51)^2 + 100*(1-x-y +0.6)^2)
  problem <- Problem(obj,cons)
  solve(problem)
}

time_res = microbenchmark(method_constroptim(),
                          method_fmincon(),
                          method_solnl(),
                          method_CVXR(),
                          times = 20)
```

Comment: beautiful ! It seems  slower(100 times) than constrOptim in my code, do you have some tips for using it ?

Comment: @Travis Could you show how you used `constrOptim`? I am curious since I don't think it is applicable when with equality constraint.

Comment: @Travis Thank you, I will have look at it

Comment: @Travis I listed several approaches for the optimization problem, you can have a look at it